# How to show bootstrap bottom pophover an image click in java script

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody tell How to show bootstrap bottom pophover an image button  click in java script

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a usefull documentation about popovers. You can read it here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Here is a simple example how to use:

```
<img src="so.jpg" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Top title" data-content="Body text" />
```

Don't forget to include `jQuery` and `bootstrap.js`. You also need to declare the popover, because it doesn't work by default, you can use this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-popover="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

This example contains also a solution for `hovering` the image. Simply replace `data-toggle="popover"` with `data-popover="popover"`.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

<img src="abc.jpg" data-toggle="popover" >
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://example/image/url" alt="image" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Content"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
    });
</script>
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp).